# Canvas WrapText function with fillText

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am creating a multiple choice quiz, however, the questions are too many characters and won't display on 1 line. I understand I have to use the wrapText function in order to paragraph it, I am just unsure how to implement this within my code. The Questions are set as strings in a variable (Questions), with the answers being strings in variable (Options). textpos1, defines the coordinates where I want my question to start, with textpos2 - textpos4 defining the coordinates where the separate answers start. These coordinates are in these positions to align to my background image.

JSFiddle here with full code however it doesn't seem to like my BG image on there...   http://jsfiddle.net/danielparry8/6U9Rn/

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var quizbg = new Image();
            var Question = new String;
            var Option1 = new String;
            var Option2 = new String;
            var Option3 = new String;
            var mx=0;                                   
            var my=0;
            var CorrectAnswer = 0;
            var qnumber = 0;
            var rightanswers=0;
            var wronganswers=0;
            var QuizFinished = false;
            var lock = false;
            var textpos1=25;
            var textpos2=145;
            var textpos3=230;
            var textpos4=325;
            var Questions = ["Which Manchester United Player won \n the 2008 Golden Boot with 31 Goals?","At which club did Bobby Charlton start his football career?","Which year did Wayne Rooney win the BBC Young Sports Personality of the year award?"];
            var Options = [["Cristiano Ronaldo","Wayne Rooney","Ryan Giggs"],["Manchester United","Manchester City","Chelsea"],["2002","2003","2004"]];
```

The 'setQuestions' function grabs the appropriate question and answers and uses fillText to apply them to the canvas, my only issue being that the Question is displayed on one continuos line.

```
   SetQuestions = function(){

                Question=Questions[qnumber];
                CorrectAnswer=1+Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

                if(CorrectAnswer==1){Option1=Options[qnumber][0];Option2=Options[qnumber][1];Option3=Options[qnumber][2];}
                if(CorrectAnswer==2){Option1=Options[qnumber][2];Option2=Options[qnumber][0];Option3=Options[qnumber][1];}
                if(CorrectAnswer==3){Option1=Options[qnumber][1];Option2=Options[qnumber][2];Option3=Options[qnumber][0];}

                context.textBaseline = "middle";
                context.font = "16pt sans-serif,Arial";
                context.fillText(Question,20,textpos1);
                context.font = "14pt sans-serif,Arial";
                context.fillText(Option1,20,textpos2);
                context.fillText(Option2,20,textpos3);
                context.fillText(Option3,20,textpos4); 
            }
```

Below is a wrapText function i have tried to implement into my design with no avail, If anyone can help that is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSize, fontFace){
       var words = text.split(' ');
       var Questions = '';
       var lineHeight=fontSize;

  context.font=fontSize+" "+fontFace;

  for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = Questions + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
    if(testWidth > maxWidth) {
      context.fillText(Questions, x, y);
      Questions = words[n] + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
    }
    else {
      Questions = testLine;
    }
  }
  context.fillText(Questions, x, y);
    return(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented with your example code.  You don't indicate exactly what you expect to be passed in the 'fontSize' argument to your 'wrapText' function, but I assumed it would be something like '16pt'.    So you have this code:

```
var lineHeight=fontSize;

context.font=fontSize+" "+fontFace;
```

so now...

```
lineHeight === '16pt'
context.font === '16 pt sans-serif,Arial'
```

Then later your code says:

```
y+= lineHeight;
```

Now you have a problem, because adding '16pt' (lineHeight) to y doesn't make any sense. The value for 'y' is is a simple integer value (representing pixels).  Trying to add the string, '16pt' to it results in a strange value and strange results.

I used the code from JSFiddle, copied it to my own sandbox.  Then I cut/pasted from above, the code for wrapText. 
I substituted for:

context.fillText(Question, 20, textpos1);

with:

wrapText(context,Question,20,textpos1,500,'16pt','sans-serif,Arial');

inside wrapText where

```
y = lineHeight;
```

instead use:

```
y = 16;
```

You should see your wrapped line.  y = 16 is just an arbitrary number I chose. It is representing pixels...it isn't the same thing as 16pt.

Comment: I haven't managed to add the wrapText function into my code yet, did you experiment with the full code from the JSFiddle (which excludes the wrapText)? I understand I have to somehow implement this wrapText function into my code, I just don't know what bits I have to change in order to get it working, Let me know if you can offer any more assistance or if I can supply you with any other information, this is my first time delving into the Canvas feature. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I added some more to my original answer.  I hope it gives you the clarification you need.

Comment: That has worked, thank you so much, if I could buy you a beer, I certainly would!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QGz2R/

If you create a "class" then you can reuse that "class" to store and draw as many questions as you need.

First, create a Question & Answer class that holds:

- the question text
- each answer text
- the bounding box of each answer that's drawn on the canvas
- the correct answer

Example Code:

```
    // a Question & Answer "class" 

    function QA(question,options,correctOption){
        this.QBB=null;  // the bounding box for the wrapped question text
        this.Q=question;
        this.A=[];
        this.correct=correctOption;
        for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
            this.A.push({text:options[i],BB:null});
        }
    }

    // Draw the question and possible answers on the canvas
    // At the same time calculate the bounding boxes(BB)
    // of each answer so that the BB can be used to test
    // if the user clicked in the correct answer

    QA.prototype.draw=function(x,y,maxWidth){
        var BB=this.QBB=wrapText(this.Q,x,y,maxWidth,14,"verdana");
        for(var i=0;i<this.A.length;i++){
            y+=BB.height;
            BB=this.A[i].BB=wrapText(i+". "+this.A[i].text,x,y,maxWidth,14,"verdana");
            ctx.strokeRect(BB.x,BB.y,BB.width,BB.height);
        }
        return({x:x,y:y});
    }

    // test if the supplied mouseX/mouseY is inside any answer

    QA.prototype.hitAnswer=function(x,y){
        for(var i=0;i<this.A.length;i++){
            var bb=this.A[i].BB;
            if(x>bb.x && x<bb.x+bb.width && y>bb.y && y<bb.y+bb.height){
                return(i);
            }
        }
        return(-1);
    }
```

Next,

- Listen for mousedown events
- Test if the user has clicked in any answer.  You do this by testing if the mouse was clicked inside the bounding box of any of the answers.
- If the user clicked in an answer alert whether they selected the correct answer or not.

Example code:

```
    // Listen for mousedown and check if the user has
    // clicked in an answer to the question

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      var answer=q.hitAnswer(mouseX,mouseY);
      if(answer==q.correct){
        $results.text("Correct! #"+q.correct+" is the answer");
      }else{
        $results.text("Sorry! #"+answer+" is not the answer");
      }

    }
```

And here is the slightly modified wrapText code that now returns the bounding box of the text it just wrapped on the canvas:

```
    // wrap the specified text and draw it to the canvas
    // and return the bounding box of that wrapped text

    function wrapText(text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSize, fontFace){
      var startY=y;
      var words = text.split(' ');
      var line = '';
      var lineHeight=fontSize+2;

      ctx.font=fontSize+" "+fontFace;

      y+=fontSize;

      for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
        var metrics = ctx.measureText(testLine);
        var testWidth = metrics.width;
        if(testWidth > maxWidth) {
          ctx.fillText(line, x, y);
          line = words[n] + ' ';
          y += lineHeight;
        }
        else {
          line = testLine;
        }
      }
      ctx.fillText(line, x, y);
      return({x:x,y:startY,width:maxWidth,height:y-startY+4});
    }
```